# Probability of a helicopter finding a crashed airplane

Tags: probability

I have been practicing for my exam and I found this question and I don't know how to solve it.

The plane can be crashed in one of the two areas:
A1: 80%
A2: 20%
there are 10 helicopters, and each helicopter has a probability of 0,2 for finding the plane and each helicopter is independent. How should you arrange the helicopters to have the best chance of finding the plane?

Now, I understand that if the plane is in the area A1, then we calculate the probability like this: 0,8 * 0,2^n, where n is the number of helicopters (1,2,3...10)
Also, if the plane is in the area A2: 0,2*0,2^(10-n)

I do not understand how to get the number of helicopters required in area 1 and 2.
Also, what would happen if we had 4 areas?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sometimes it helps to look at the complementary event. Can you say what the probability is that the plane is not found?

Comment: @soakley, I need to calculate what is the best way to arrange the helicopters, ex: in area 1 we should have 7 helicopters and in area 2 3 helicopters to have the best chance of finding the plane..

Comment: Yes. So let $n$ be the number of helicopters sent to area A1. Can you find the expression for the probability that the plane is not found?

Comment: For not finding the plane in area1: 0,8 * 0,8^n
not finding it in area2: 02* 08^(10-n)

Comment: Ok, so combining with the expression for area 2, how can you minimize the probability of missing the plane?

Comment: i am not sure... :/

Comment: Well, worst case is explicit enumeration. There are only 11 possibilities.

Comment: oh, I get it. When I calculate for 0,8*0,8^n + 0,2*0,8^(10-n) where n={0,1,2...10}, the lowest value is when n=8, which means not finding the plane has the lowest probability (0.262218) when we have 8 helicopters in A1 and 2 in A2.
@soakley, I don't get why this didn't work for P(finding the plane)=0,8*0,2^n + 0,2*0,2^(10-n)?

Comment: To go after the solution directly is trickier. You have to consider the chance that 1 helicopter finds the plane plus the chance that 2 helicopters find it, etcetera, all the way up to all 10 helicopters finding the plane. Now you see why the complementary event is useful - you just need to find the chance that zero helicopters find the plane.

Comment: thank you very much @soakley!

Comment: You're very welcome. See below for a method to avoid full enumeration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of not finding the plane, as we found in the comments, is given by $$f(n) = (0.8)^{n+1} + (0.2)(0.8)^{10-n},$$ where $n$ is the number of helicopters sent to A1.

To minimize this, we take the derivative and set equal to zero. $$f'(n)=(0.8)^{n+1} \ln(0.8)-(0.2)(0.8)^{10-n} \ln(0.8)=0$$

Simplifying, we find $$(0.8)^{2n-9} = 0.2,$$

which, when solved for $n,$ gives $$n = {{1 \over 2}} \left( {\ln(0.2) \over \ln(0.8)}+9 \right) \approx 8.11$$

I leave it to the reader to check the second derivative verifying this is a minimum. Evalating $f(n)$ at $n=8$ gives the lowest probability of not finding the plane at 0.262218, so the probability of finding the plane is 0.737782

Since this is a discrete problem, we should check $n=9$ also, which confirms that $n=8$ is the optimal solution as the success probability is only 0.732626 when $n=9.$